# How to use Euler formula to prove the following conclusion

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I only know how to prove it use Fourier series.
$$\ln(\sin{x})=-\ln2-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2kx)}{k}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
\log (\sin x) = \Re \log (\sin x) = \Re \log \left( {\frac{{e^{ix}  - e^{ - ix} }}{{2i}}} \right) =  - \log 2 + \Re \log (1 - e^{ - 2ix} ).
$$

Comment: Why just keep the real part?

Comment: I assume that $\sin x>0$, so for example $0<x<\pi$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{cos(2k x)}k$$

$=$ the real part of $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{(e^{2ix})^k}k=-\ln(1-e^{2ix})$$

Now $\ln(1-e^{2ix})$

$\equiv\ln(-1)+\ln(e^{ix})+\ln(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})\pmod{2\pi i}$

$\equiv i\pi+ix+\ln(2i\sin x)\pmod{2\pi i}$

$\equiv i\pi+ix+\ln2+\ln(\sin x)+\ln i$

whose real part is $\ln2+\ln(\sin x)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer,But I want to know how to derive from \ln(\sin(x))